# IIS probleme : 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

I can't run my .NET applications on IIS , it always says : 404 not found 
when I tried localhost it works but the default web site can't work and even any application under it doesn't work and an error message appear says that this file not found in the server. I can't understand the problem 
[here the error message when i try to open any of my applications[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNNWD.png)

[here the list of all my applications under the default web site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fnlz.png)

[here how it works when I tape localhost or my IP @](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjxhP.png)

Comment: Could you please tell me hwat you mean about default web site can't work and even any application  it doesn't work? Could you please post the url which you faced the 404 error message?

Comment: @BrandoZhang this is the URL that it does nor work http://localhost:8080/MAINTA_FORMBin

Comment: As far as I know, the default web site's port number is 80 not 8080. I suggest you could try to use  localhost:80/MAINTA_FORMBin to access the web sites.

Answer (score 0):

Open the hosts file in the below location "**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**"
at this file, there is an enter for the localhost

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

add another line for the server, example the adress of the server is **192.168.2.3**, add a new line for the server

```
192.168.2.3   Myserver name
```

This file represent a reference for the server to find a corresponding IP Address and Server name.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that the server can not resolve the IP address based on a name. A configration of the Hosts file is necessary. In this file, there is a default configuration for localhost.
try to add a line for the server name and IP address.
The Hosts file is in the following location.

```
C: \ WINDOWS \ system32 \ drivers \ etc \ hosts
```

Comment: thanx for ur interaction , How can I add this line (I'm not a professional at IIS)